# Want to display image by giving its path but page is not showing images, although the path is correct

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

The code is displaying the contents of DB only images are not showing

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Password</th>        
            <th>Image</th>        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach($users as  $user)
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->password}}</td>
            <td> <img src="storage/app/fileToUpload/{{ $user->pic }}" style="height:100; width:100" /></td>
            </tr>        
        @endforeach
    <input type="hidden" value={{csrf_token()}} name=_token>
  </table>
```

Only problem with:

```
<td> <img src="storage/app/fileToUpload/{{ $user->pic }}" style="height:100; width:100" /></td>
```

Comment: change it to img src="storage/app/fileToUpload/".{{ $user->pic }}

Comment: Have you applied `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: Check the meta data of the page also. Is it allowed to include inline img src or not?

Comment: @Satya I have already applied but not working

Comment: what value you are getting of {{ $user->pic }}?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada yup still not working

Comment: @ShivendraSingh I am getting values from db, the column name in which I have saved image is pic and each path is like:fileToUpload/G1ckuoco7XslcMsVaeRni9RomulXUBGjwVoxH.jpeg

Comment: While my browser is showing:
<img src="fileToUpload/" .="" style="height:100; width:100">

Comment: Try with 

    `<td> <img src="{{ storage_path('app/fileToUpload') . $user->pic }}" style="height:100; width:100" /></td>`

Answer (score -3):

You should try this:

```
<td> <img src="storage/app/fileToUpload/".{{ $user->pic }} style="height:100; width:100" /></td>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be <img src="storage/app/fileToUpload/".{{ $user->pic }} in your answer

Comment: Why should one try that? Can oyu explain what you've changed, besides broken markup? The URL generated by the current snippet will only contain `storage/app/fileToUpload/` while there will be some dynamic string outside that `src` attribute